# Mezzanine Floor

Tags: wood, floor, structural, beam

I want to install a mezzanine floor that will only be used as a play area for children. The span is 8.7 feet by 9.4 feet.

My plan is to fix 8" x 2" beam to 3 walls and then run 6" x 1.5" beams across the 8.7' span at intervals of 18' apart.

My gut tells me this is way over designed but can someone with the necessary structural knowledge perhaps give me a few pointers.

Comment: Over design is always much better than under design.  8.7 span I would use 2x8s at 16in, unless the wood is known for quality/grade.  A mezzanine floor(section above) making sure children can't climb over and fall is important.  Do not need to give them more ideas to hurt themselves.

Comment: That is my rule of thumb as well, 1" of dimension for every foot of run. 8' span uses 2X8 10' span uses 2x10 etc.. the last joist at the unsupported edge (open side???), I guess the 4th side since you refer to 3 walls already would be doubled.